# Run JS functions in parallel awiting one of them

Tags: javascript

So i have a main function that calls two other functions, one of witch i have to await for result, so each funtion needs to be called separatly as they are trigered in different parts of the code, but test1 funct can run in parallel and i don't need the result, but test2 needs to provide a result.

I like for both functions to run in parallel..

this is my code so far.. cant get the two request to happen in parallel.

```
function test1() {
  yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com/'

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", yourUrl, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    console.log('get pedido')
  }
  xhr.send()
}

async function test2() {
  yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com'

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", yourUrl, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    console.log('get precio')
  }
  xhr.send()

  return true
}

async function main() {
  test1()
  await test2()
}

main()
```

Comment: JS is single threaded so they won't technically be happening in parallel. But looking at your code, definitely second request is fired before first is completed. Are you sure you are checking correctly?

Comment: `test2` doesn't wait for the AJAX request to complete before it returns.  So there's no point in using `async/await`. You need an explicit `Promise` that gets resolved in the `onload` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AJAX requests are already being sent concurrently, I don't think that's your actual problem.

If you want `test2` to wait for the response before it returns, you need to use a `Promise`.

```js
function test2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com'

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", yourUrl, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      xhr.onload = function(e) {
        console.log('get precio');
        resolve(true);
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
  })
}
```

You can simplify and modernize the code by using `fetch()`, which returns a promise.

```js
async function test2() {
  yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com'
  await fetch(yourUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  console.log('get precio');
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute both at the same time you could use fetch instead of xhr,
if xhr is required to use you could create a promise based on xhr

```js
function getData(yourUrl, method="POST"){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, yourUrl, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            console.log('get pedido')
            resolve() //PASS DATA TO NEXT .then
        }    
        xhr.send()
    )
}

    
function test1(){

    yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com/'
    return getData(yourUrl)

}

function test2(){
    yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com/'
    return getData(yourUrl)
}

function main(){
  Promise.all([test1,test2])
    .then(res => console.log(res[0], res[1])
}

//EASIER SOLUTION 

function test1(){
  const yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com/';
  return fetch(yourUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    // if plain text res.text()
}
function test2(){
    const yourUrl = 'http://www.google.com'
    return fetch(yourUrl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      // if plain text res.text()
}
function main(){
  Promise.all([test1,test2])
    .then(res => console.log(res[0], res[1])
}
```

You could create as well your own promises and use Promise.all, Promise.all will execute and return both responses

Comment: Just to complete my answer, requests should be happening already asynchronously in xhr, if you need test1 to execute first use a callback if promise isnt possible